# How can I write an SQL query offset by x rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to get x rows from a table that are offset by x rows and ordered by a date column.

The problem I have is I'm paginating the rows from the query into pages of 10 rows per page, but I only need the nth page.

For example if I only need page 4 from the table, I need to select all the rows:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date
```

Then I need to paginate the array using PHP and get the 4th page (if it exists). This is less than ideal as it seems a waste to have to get the whole table.

Is there a better way to query the table in this situation?. For example if I have 10 posts per page and I want the the 4th page, is there a way to offset the query so it starts from the 30th row? (and ordered by date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIMIT is the answer. According to MySQL documentation,

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Comment: Oh I didn't know you could do this. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3143218 Never mind. Next time, just make sure you google something first. :D

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date LIMIT 10, 20
```

Where 10 is offset and 20 is the number of rows